# Difficulty on creating a display of a statistic in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph

It's my first question on stack overflow, I will try to keep it clear, but I apologise in advance if anything is wrong.

I am currently working on a display for some statistics, which are in variable number, names and values, which can be assimiled with a percentage, and are "for" and "against" a decision. The end result should, ideally, look like the image I added.

[image]

I've tried using diverse swing elements in order to do that, but I can't display the name of the statistic (sneezing, etc) over the bar, and I can't color a label background only partially. Do you have any solution?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to display. Best is to post [mcve] to show what you have and what problems you face

Comment: There are many ways to create graphical display you describe. You didn't give us information about how you tried to implement this. In case you haven't started yet I suggest that you start with `JPanel`, that will be that white area with cut off corner. Give this panel `GridBagLayout` and set it up to display components in a column. Then extend `JLabel` and override its `paintComponent` method in such way that you can control how much of the background is painted. These will be the horizontal bars. Put it all together and make it display appropriate model.